# Выборка данных из бд

Tags: mysql, php, codeigniter, mvc

Добрый день!

У меня есть 2 поля выборки select. Раньше не требовалось, чтобы поля option брались с бд. И поэтому я им сразу присвоила значение и все замечательно работает. Но вот сейчас возник вопрос и мне нужно, чтобы поля select выбирались из базы. Как это можно сделать, не рушив все остальное. (Просто не очень давно занимаюсь php)

```
<select name="arendator">
    <option value="Все">Все</option>
    <option value="ЮГРК">ЮГРК</option>
    <option value="Тулачермет">Тулачермет</option>
    <option value="СУЭК">СУЭК</option>
<select>
```

Контроллер

```
public function DislocationResult() // Результат выборки дислокации
{
    $sobstvenik = $this->input->post('sobstvenik');
    $arendator =  $this->input->post('arendator');
    $napravlenie = $this->input->post('napravlenie');
    $seldate = $this->input->post('seldate');
    $disla['sobstvenik'] = $sobstvenik;
    $disla['arendator'] = $arendator;
    $disla['napravlenie'] = $napravlenie;
    $disla = $this->Unload_model->disla_result($sobstvenik, $arendator, $napravlenie, $seldate);
    $data['disla'] = $disla;
    $this->load->view('pages_view/disla_result_view', $data);
}
```

Модель

```
public function disla_result($sobstvenik, $arendator, $napravlenie, $seldate) // Выборка дислокации
{
    $sql = "SELECT nd. * , vs. * 
                    FROM newdisla nd
                    JOIN (
                    SELECT number_vagona, max( disla_date ) maxdate
                    FROM newdisla
                    WHERE disla_date <= '" . $seldate . "'
                    GROUP BY number_vagona
                    )t ON ( nd.number_vagona = t.number_vagona
                    AND nd.disla_date = t.maxdate ) , vagon_status vs
                    WHERE t.number_vagona = vs.number_vagona";
    if ($sobstvenik != "Все") {
        $sql = $sql . " and vs.sobstvenik='" . $sobstvenik . "'";
    }
    if ($arendator != "Все") {
        $sql = $sql . " and vs.arendator='" . $arendator . "'";
    }
    if ($napravlenie != "Все") {
        $sql = $sql . " and vs.napravlenie='" . $napravlenie . "'";
    }

    $sql = $sql . " order by nd.naznachenie, nd.operation";

    $res = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($res) {
        return $res->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: т.е. сейчас когда я выбираю занчение в select к примеру ЮГРК, то у меня в моделе где арендатор = $arendator присваивается ЮГРК. ну как то так. а теперь мне нужно чтобы селект выбирался из бд

Comment: Выбираете нужные значения, присваиваете необходимому view, рендерите циклом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стал разбираться в коде на PHP
Просто скажу как это легко сделать в логическом смысле:
Поскольку в PHP нет удобных Контролов с датабиндингом поэтому самый очевидный вариант сделать циклическое заполнение html
`<select name="renter">
<?php 
 foreach ( $item in $data['renters'] ){
   print ("<option value=\"".$item['id']."\" >".$item['name']."</option>\n");
}
?>
</select>`

Всё что нужно, это сделать селект из бд
что-то вроде такого:

`SELECT id, name FROM renter`
И записать его в $data['renters'];
PS: Учите английский, и читайте книги.